# The easiest error you have ever seen

Tags: android, database

piece of my MainClass.java

```
     int l = 0;
        int p = 0;
        ShopHandler sh = new ShopHandler(this);
        int u = sh.getShopCount();
        String[] Shops = new String[u];
        String[] ShopsApproved = new String[u];
        for (int i=0;i<u;i++)
        {
            Shops[i]=sh.getShop(i+1).getShop();
        }
        float[] prices = new float[u];
        for(int i=0;i<u;i++)
        {
            Shop shop = sh.getShop(i+1);
            ShopName = shop.getShop();
            ProductHandler ph = new ProductHandler(this);
            int o = ph.getProductsCount();
            for(int j=0;j<o;j++)
            {
                Product prod = ph.getProduct(j+1);          //Always null
                String productname = prod.getName();
                if(productname==SearchProduct)
                {
                    ShopsApproved[++l]=ShopName;
                    prices[++p]=ph.getProduct(j+1).getPrice();
                }
            }
        }
```

piece my of ProductHandler.java

```
        // Getting single product
        Product getProduct(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, new String[] { KEY_NAME,
                KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_TYPE, KEY_PRICE }, KEY_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        Product product = null;                          //Start
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {                      

            product = new Product(cursor.getString(0), Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(1)),
                    Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)), Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(3)));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return product;                              //end
    }
```

So what the problem is? When you look up you will see marked by commentary code. It always return null to the also marked code in MainClass. if you know where the problem is, please write it to the answers.
Product database:

```
Name    Amount   Type   Price 
Cheese   1.0      1     5.34 
Milk     1.0      2     3.67 
Cola     2.0      2     7.05
```

Comment: have you stepped through with the debugger to see what is going on? have you checked that you have at least 2 items in the database (assuming it is 0 indexed)? What have you tried yourself to fix this problem before asking StackOverflow to do it for you?

Comment: in where clause you using i+1 to filter with name ?? are you have name with this values ??

Comment: @panini yes i tried to fix it by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And most likely your cursor is returning null results is because you are looking for a name in your query, but passing it an ID:

```
KEY_NAME + "=?",
new String[] { String.valueOf(id) },
```

Does your data include an "_id" column or index?

Answer (score 1):

One can only speculate without knowing the actual table and its data. But most likely, the query is not returning any records, causing `cursor.moveToFirst()` to always return false.